# In PostgreSQL and Oracle, when are NULL and empty string treated the same?

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql

I created the following dbfiddle, in which you can see that *field <> ''* rules out the case where *field* is null.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xdfayYMvdRZDRRASvGFdpT/0

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  prd_typ_cd bpchar,
  prd_prnt_typ_cd bpchar,
  prd_chld_typ_cd bpchar
);
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('SHC', null, 'DIV');

INSERT INTO test VALUES ('DIV', 'SHC', 'DEP');

INSERT INTO test VALUES ('DEP', 'DIV', null);

SELECT * FROM test WHERE prd_chld_typ_cd <> '';
```

I was surprised to see this, since in most languages NULL and '' (empty string) are treated differently.

The above example is from a PostgreSQL database. Would the same be true on an Oracle database? Under what circumstances do PostgreSQL and Oracle treated NULL and '' (empty string) as the same thing?

Comment: Never. You may be misled by some software (database browsers) which show nulls as empty strings.

Answer (score 5):

`NULL` *and* `''` *ARE* being treated differently in Postgres.

```
 prd_chld_typ_cd <> ''
```

returns `NULL` when `prd_chld_typ_cd` is `NULL`.  This is typical behavior for most operations involving `NULL`.  You will readily find that:

```
 prd_chld_typ_cd = ''
```

behaves exactly the same when that column is `NULL`.

For any other value, the expression returns true or false.  You would readily see this if you returned the value:

```
SELECT t.*, prd_chld_typ_cd <> ''
FROM test t;
```

What is happening is that `NULL` and false are treated the same way in a `WHERE` filter -- both filter out the row.

By contrast, `NULL` and `''` are synonyms in Oracle.  But it turns out that

```
 prd_chld_typ_cd <> ''
 prd_chld_typ_cd = ''
```

Both behave the same way when `prd_chld_typ_cd` is `NULL`.  Alas, though, in Oracle, both *always* return `NULL` -- because `''` is equivalent to `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about postgres, but oracle has some quirks about empty strings you need to be aware about if you are planning to support it in your applications:

1. in Oracle the empty string is ALWAYS considered NULL: if you insert an empty string, you will read back a NULL. In oracle the empty string simply does not exist: it is just "syntax sugar" if you can write '' instead of NULL, when dealing with varchar values.
2. In Oracle the expression  ('' is null)
   will evaluate to TRUE. the empty string is DE FACTO null
3. In oracle any comparison involving a NULL value will ALWAYS evaluate to FALSE. This means that the only operators you can apply to NULL values and that can return TRUE are "is null" and "is not null"

The consequence of the above is that, in oracle, ALL the following expressions will evaluate to FALSE, regardless of the actual value of myvar:

```
 myvar = '' 
 myvar <> '' 
 myvar = null
 myvar <> null
```

even these evaluate always to false

```
 null = null
 null <> null
 null = '' 
 null <> ''
```

so the following update will not update anything:

```
 update mytab set myfield ='X' where myfield = ''
```

as I said, you can only use the 'is null' and 'is not null' operators.
so you must write it as

```
update mytab set myfield='X' where myfield is null.
```

P. S. the only oracle function that treats null as a distinct comparable value is Decode(). probably this was born as a bug, but today there is too much software that relies on this behaviour to fix it.

```
  decode( <expression>,
          <caseval 1>,  < exitval 1>,
          <caseval 2>,  < exitval 2>,
          .... 
           <elseval>)
```

If replace the "decode" with the equivalent sql standard "case" construct, it won't work: oracle didn't replicate the decode bug when implementing the case syntax